# Make a toast when parsing data from json

Tags: android, json

My JSON file looks like [{"Delay":5}] I need to check if Delay is not 0 then put it in toast like (Delay = 5 ) but when I run the application stop and don't show anything

```
    private void Affiche (){
        StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, URL_WAITING,
                new Response.Listener<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String response) {
                        try {
                            JSONArray waiting = new JSONArray(response);

                            for (int i = 0; i < waiting.length(); i++) {
           JSONObject productObject = waiting.getJSONObject(i);
                                int Delay = productObject.getInt("Delay");
                                if ( Delay ==0) {

                                }else {
Toast.makeText(WaitingActivity.this, Delay, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
                                }

                                }

                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                },
                new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                   Toast.makeText(WaitingActivity.this, error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                });

        Volley.newRequestQueue(this).add(stringRequest);
```

I expect to show "Delay = 5" but it didn't show anything

Comment: What does the value of response equal?

Comment: Have you debugged to the point? Are you sure the listener (the method `onResponse`) gets ever executed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If by "when I run the application stop" you mean that the app is crashing, then that's probably because you are trying to show an `int` instead of a `String`. 
 The `makeText()` method accepts either an `Int` or a `CharSequence` as the second parameter, but the `int` that it accepts refers to a resource id. So in your case, since your `int` is not referring to a resource id, you might want to convert your `Delay` variable to a `String` in order to show it in a `Toast`. 
Example.

```
String delayString = "Delay = " + Integer.toString(Delay);
Toast.makeText(WaitingActivity.this, delayString, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

Comment: Thank you, now it show "5" but how can I add a messege to it ? I want to show "Delay = 5 ".

Comment: Toast.makeText(WaitingActivity.this, "Delay = " + delayString, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

This will do the work!